# How can I add headers for authorization and content-type in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http-headers

I have this code to call API;
how can I  add authorization and content-type headers to this?

```dart
  final url = Uri.parse('https://api.collectapi.com/economy/hisseSenedi');
  var counter;
  var hisseResult;
  Future callHisse() async {
    try{
      final response = await http.get(url);

      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var result = hisselistFromJson(response.body);
        if(mounted);
        setState(() {
          counter = result.data.length;
          hisseResult = result;
        });
        return result;
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this:

```
Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
       'Content-type': 'application/json',
       'Authorization': '<Your token>'
     };

final response = await http.get(url,headers:requestHeaders);
```